# react-native-fbsdk-next after authenticating I see this message

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-native-fbsdk-next

Using the react-native-fbsdk-next library, after logging in with Facebook I get this message

I'm using

```
LoginManager.logInWithPermissions(["public_profile"]).then(
            function(result) {
                if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log("Login cancelled");
                } else {
                    console.log(
                        "Login success with permissions: " +
                        result.grantedPermissions.toString()
                    );
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log("Login fail with error: " + error);
            }
        );
```

[image]

`version react-native-fbsdk-next "^12.1.2"`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.3
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M1
    Memory: 37.31 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.17.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.8.1 - ~/Documents/nueva-version/facebook-signin/node_modules/.bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.08.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738
    Xcode: 14.2/14C18 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.16.1 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.7 => 0.71.7 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

parece que esta aplicación no está disponible, para solucionar este problema ponte en contacto con myapp fecebook

> It seems that this application is not available, to solve this problem contact

Comment: I think you should check your steps again

Comment: maybe you miss something when config package

Answer (score 1):

The public_profile is not available if your facebook account is set to "Business".
To solve that you'll have to change your Facebook Business Login to Facebook Login.

You can find it using this [source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business/):

**Supported Permissions**

*You may request the following permissions from your business clients. Note that unlike Facebook Login, Facebook Login for Business requires your business client to grant all of the permissions that you specify in your configuration.
The email and public_profile permissions are automatically granted to all apps. However, they must be used with at least one other supported permission for each app installation.
The public_profile permission is automatically granted to all apps however it will not be returned in the scope parameter unless at least one other supported permission, excluding email, is granted by an app user.*

The solution will be:

**Switch to Facebook Login**

*If your app is not functioning as intended after switching to Facebook Login for Business, you can uninstall it by rolling back to Facebook Login by going to the App Dashboard > Facebook Login for Business > Settings and clicking the Switch to Facebook Login link. You will be presented with a survey which helps us improve the Facebook Login for Business configuration experience. Each app is allowed to roll back to Facebook Login within 30 days after the switch and can only roll-back max three times.*

Hope that helps.
It fixed the same issue for me.